# Where do I get hourly temperature data for cities with a high spatial resolution?

Tags: geospatial, climate

I want to do a project with very high spatial resolution temperature data from a city (any city) with very high resolution (<10 m), in an attempt to create an animated 3D microclimate map for that city (kind of a 3D heatmap).

The data would probably have to be raster data and it should be a time series of any kind (preferably hourly but could also be daily, the goal here is to test the 3D animated presentation). Where could I get such data?

Comment: related? https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/3691/1511

Comment: Well, I have already looked on some sites that provide spatio-temporal data, like https://climatedataguide.ucar.edu. I'm still in the process of evaluating what I can find there, but I'm really not sure if the data suffices, because of the high spatial resolution I need.

Comment: like on StackOverflow, a good question will describe what you tried (with links), and why they don't fit your need.